Custom templates not used when "Do not cache markup" disabled
I developed a series of custom form templates using a combination of THEME.theme hooks:
function THEME_theme_suggestions_input_alter(array &$suggestions, array &$variables, $hook){
  if (isset($variables['element']['#id'])) {
    $id = str_replace("-", "_", $variables['element']['#id']);
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $id;
  }
}
function THEME_theme_suggestions_fieldset_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook){
  if (isset($variables['element']['#id'])) {
    $id = str_replace("-", "_", $variables['element']['#id']);
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $id;
  }
}

Along with https://www.drupal.org/project/formdazzle
When the Do not cache markup is enabled on /admin/config/development/settings these templates work as expected. When not enabled, the templates are not used. Clearing the cache [either by performance or drush CR] does not fix this.
I am on Drupal 11.0.9
